# Somar ou subtrair valor de um campo em um banco dados com CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Estou usando CodeIgniter na minha aplicação, o que preciso fazer é o seguinte eu tenho em meu banco de dados um campo com nome estoque, esse campo é valor inteiro, eu preciso fazer o seguinte quando eu realizar uma venda ele terá que diminuir a quantidade da minha venda desse campo, no PHP seria alguma coisa mais ou menos assim.

```
$sql = mysql_query( sprintf( “UPDATE profile_posts SET cliks = cliks + 1 WHERE id = %d” , $id ) )
    or die( mysql_error( ) );
```

Existe algum recurso do CodeIgniter que posso fazer isso ou terei que fazer um SQL específico pra isso:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja um exemplo da [*DOC*](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)

```
$data = array( 'title' => $title , 'name'  => $name );
$this-> db-> where( 'id' , $id );
$this-> db-> update( 'mytable' , $data );
```

Sua query pode ser escrita da seguinte forma, usando `set` para atribuir a contagem

```
$this->db-> where( 'id' , $id );
$this->db-> set( array( 'cliks' => 'cliks-1' ) );
$this->db-> update( 'profile_posts' );
```

---

> eu preciso fazer o seguinte quando eu realizar uma venda ele terá que **diminuir** a quantidade

Embora sua query esteja `cliks + 1`, suponho que você tenha errado o sinal.